# How to cleanup sockets after mono-process crashes?

Tags: unix, mono, asyncsocket

I am creating a chat server in mono that should be able to have many sockets open. Before deciding on the architecture, I am doing a load test with mono. Just for a test, I created a small mono-server and mono-server that opens 100,000 sockets/connections and it works pretty well.

I tried to hit the limit and at sometime the process crashes (of course).
But what worries me is that if I try to restart the process, it directly gives "Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Too many open files".

So I guess that somehow the filedescriptions(sockets) are kept open even when my process ends. Even several hours later it still gives this error, the only way I can deal with it is to reboot my computer. We cannot run into this kind of problem if we are in production without knowing how to handle it.

**My question:**
Is there anything in Mono that keeps running globally regardless of which mono application is started, a kind of service I can restart without rebooting my computer? 
Or is this not a mono problem but a unix problem, that we would run into even if we would program it in java/C++?

I checked the following, but no mono processes alive, no sockets open and no files:

```
localhost:~ root# ps -ax | grep mono  
1536 ttys002    0:00.00 grep mono
```

-

```
localhost:~ root# lsof | grep mono  
(nothing)
```

-

```
localhost:~ root# netstat -a  
Active Internet connections (including servers)  
(no unusual ports are open)
```

For development I run under OSX 10.7.5. For production we can decide which platform to use.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need to set (or unset) the Linger option on the socket (using [Socket.SetSocketOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e160993d.aspx). Depending on the actual API you're using there might be better alternatives (TcpClient has a [LingerState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.lingerstate.aspx) property for instance).